# Flutter AppBarTheme not applied to AppBar by default

Tags: flutter, dart, styling, appbar

I was tryng to apply a theme to my appBar by default.
I assigned the theme to my material app.
I was expecting appBar without a style to automatically inherit from this theme such as other components (aka dividerTheme in this example).
Do I have to manually associate each bar to the theme using Theme.of(context) ?

My Theme

```
final theme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  primaryColor: Colors.blue,
  accentColor: Colors.blueAccent,
  accentColorBrightness: Brightness.light,

  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  ),

  dividerTheme: DividerThemeData(
    thickness: 4,
    color: Colors.white,
    indent: 10,
    endIndent: 10,),
)
```

What doesn't work:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: ...
          ...
```

In this case AppBar doesn't inherit the background color defined in theme.

What it works instead:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          title: ...
          ...

...
```

Also If I wanted to define a shape or a height that doesn't even exist in AppBarTheme and I had to extend AppBar class to achieve what I needed:

is this approach correct:

My themed app bar:

```
class ThemedAppBar extends AppBar {
  final Widget? title;
  final List<Widget>? actions;
  ThemedAppBar({this.actions, this.title})
      : super(
          toolbarHeight: 70,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          leadingWidth: 70,
          centerTitle: true,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
            ),
          ),
          actions: actions,
          title: title,
        );
}
```

and using this instead of AppBar:

```
@override
  Widget Scaffold(
        appBar: ThemedAppBar(
          title: ...
          ...
```

Is this the correct approach or am I missing something.
Why Theme works for divider but not app bar styling ?